# Split object and group it

Tags: javascript, lodash

I need a proper way to split this object and group it.
Thank you in advance

```
let data = [{
    name: 'DAVID/JOHN',
    amount: '1231.21/131.93',
    identity: '1880/1332',
    address: 'first/second'
  }]
```

Expected result

```
  let result = [
    {
      name: 'DAVID',
      amount: '1231.21',
      identity: '1880',
      address: 'first'
    },
    {
      name: 'JOHN',
      amount: '131.93',
      identity: '1332',
      address: 'second'
    }
  ]
```

Comment: What have you tried? [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`Array.flatMap()][1]` or lodash's [`_.flatMap()`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.11#flatMap) to iterate the array, take the [entries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) of each object, and split them to multiple objects with [`Array.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) and [`Array.forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach):

```js
let data = [{
  name: 'DAVID/JOHN',
  amount: '1231.21/131.93',
  identity: '1880/1332',
  address: 'first/second'
}]

const result = data.flatMap(o =>
  Object.entries(o)
  .reduce((r, [k, v]) => {
    v.split('/').forEach((p, i) => {
      if (!r[i]) r[i] = {}

      r[i][k] = p;
    })

    return r
  }, [])
)

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 3):

Here using a map method.

```js
let data = [{
    name: 'DAVID/JOHN',
    amount: '1231.21/131.93',
    identity: '1880/1332',
    address: 'first/second'
  }]

let result = data.flatMap(e => {
  return e.name.split('/').map((v,i) => {
    return {
      name: v,
      amount: e.amount.split('/')[i],
      identity: e.identity.split('/')[i],
      address: e.address.split('/')[i]
    }
  });
});

console.log(result);
```

Comment: You can use flatMap (`data.flatMap`) instead of using map and then flat.

Comment: @OriDrori yes I saw that on your answer. I will be using it :). It will edit my answer here. Thanks !!